# How to show/hide new <div> near <div> by mouseover/mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opera

I have a  container (main container), when mouse over on it - shows new  container (addition container) near main container. While mouse over this containers (main container and addition container) addition container stay on screen. When mouse out main container or addition container - addition container hides. Problem: in opera addition container do not stay on screen.

HTML:

```
<div style='float:left; width:100px;' class='triggerShowHidePanel' panelID='1'>    
--- main content ---    
<div class='categoryContainer1' style='float:left; display:none; width:100px;'>
--- addition content ---    
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.triggerShowHidePanel').bind('mouseover', function() {
    var positionX = $(this).position().top;
    var positionY = $(this).position().left + 100;
    $('.categoryContainer' + $(this).attr('panelID')).show();
    $('.categoryContainer' + $(this).attr('panelID')).offset({ 
        top: Math.round(positionX), 
        left: Math.round(positionY)
    });     
}).bind('mouseout', function() {
    $('.categoryContainer' + $(this).attr('panelID')).hide();
    $('.categoryContainer' + $(this).attr('panelID')).offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
});
```

Comment: you want to this type? http://jsfiddle.net/gUap5/1/

Comment: "--- addition content ---" must be on screen while mouse over on main content or addition content.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gUap5/5/

I added a container `div` to bind the mouseover and mouseout events to both elements.

Comment: It still do not working in opera/ When I try in addition block display links and role mouse over on it block hides http://jsfiddle.net/gUap5/7/

Comment: Well, it is working on my side (Opera 15 on Mac). They recently switched to webkit, maybe you have an older version with their own engine. Which version are you using?

Comment: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16